# Laravel pass value from foreach loop in controller to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I am trying to get the data from a `foreach` loop in my controller to pass to my view. How do I do it?

**Controller**

```js
class FormteachersController extends Controller
{
    public function form_teachers_view(){
        $UniqueStudent = Student::where('Student_ClassID','JSS 1C')->get();
        foreach ($UniqueStudent as $keydata) {
            $student = $keydata->Stud_id;
            $result= Result::where('Term_ID','1st Term')->where('Student_ID',$student)->where('Class_ID','JSS 1C')->where('Session_ID','2225/2222')->get();
            foreach ($result as $keyresult) {
                echo '<br>'.'<br>'.$student.'-'.$result;
            }
            return view('teachers.form_teachers_comment_sec');
        }
    }
}
```

This is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsXBv.png).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class FormteachersController extends Controller
{
    public function form_teachers_view(){
        $uniqueStudent = Student::where('Student_ClassID','JSS 1C')->get();
        $uniqueStudentsData = [] ;
        foreach ($uniqueStudent as $keydata) {
            $student = $keydata->Stud_id;
            $result = Result::where('Term_ID','1st Term')->where('Student_ID',$student)->where('Class_ID','JSS 1C')->where('Session_ID','2225/2222')->get();
            foreach ($result as $keyresult) {
                $uniqueStudentsData[] = '<br>'.'<br>'. $student.'-'. $keyresult;
            }
        }

        return view('teachers.form_teachers_comment_sec', compact('uniqueStudentsData'));

        // or pass array

        return view('teachers.form_teachers_comment_sec',[
            'uniqueStudentsData' => $uniqueStudentsData,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now, in your `form_teachers_comment_sec.blade.php`, run your foreach loop and do what do you want to there

```
// $uniqueStudentsData
@foreach($uniqueStudentsData as $data)
        // do what do you want
@endforeach
```

Hopefully, it will be work. more documentation please visit [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com)

Comment: I don't think this will work, since he's looping through each `$UniqueStudent ` only the first `$results` will be sent to the view.

Comment: @Makdous Good point, but I was mention how to pass a parameter to view

Comment: Thanks Guys @HashemiRafsan that your code works normally, but what I was trying to do was to send individual values of the inner loop ----foreach ($result as $keyresult)--- to the view tying to the key of the outer loop.....Anyway thanks a million you guys are great